# PowerShell Regex to filter universal diff file

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I have a diff file that I am pulling into a script and want to match only on the changes -- I don't care about the context lines or file paths; they are irrelevant.

```
--- \\path\to\file2.txt 2018-12-27 12:11:20.000000000 -0600
+++ \\path\to\file2.txt 2018-12-27 12:11:24.000000000 -0600
@@ -259,13 +259,12 @@
 18684944<tab>10-01-20<tab>5.00
-21400198<tab>12-03-18<tab>75.21
 18684944<tab>10-11-20<tab>5.00
@@ -333,13 +332,12 @@
 26085691<tab>12-17-19<tab>144.28
-21400541<tab>12-03-18<tab>72.30
 21400541<tab>01-03-19<tab>72.30

$p = @("^\+[.]*$", "^-[.]*$")
Get-Content $file| Select-String -Pattern $p
```

Expected result is a variable containing:

```
-21400198<tab>12-03-18<tab>75.21
-21400541<tab>12-03-18<tab>72.30
```

I am terrible at regex and after futzing around with various expressions am putting it up here.

Comment: is the 3-line pattern consistent? does the target line always start with a hyphen?

Comment: `Get-Content $file|Select-Object -Skip 2 | Select-String '^[+-]'`

Comment: It's actually more than 3 lines the diff program adds like 5 or 6 context lines before/after. I need the output identifying changed lines--so I am looking for anything starting with a single + or -.

Comment: Imagine what exactly my above line does?

Comment: @Ryan.James - this `'^-[^-].+$'` will match any line that starts with a hyphen and has "not a hyphen" as the next character. using your sample data and the `-match` operator, i got those two lines.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The text is indented by one space to have room for drop / add markers `-/+`, so it should be sufficient to skip the first two lines naming the diff input files. A regular aka changed line **could** possibly start with a `-` so it makes no sense to exclude them.

Comment: @LotPings -  i somehow managed to miss the `- OR +` ... but the OP stated "starts with a single + or -`. i think it best to ask the OP for confirmation ... i'll do that now! [*grin*]

Comment: @Ryan.James - does the wanted line always start with a _single_ plus-or-minus? will it ever have something like a "<hyphen><negative sign><other stiff>`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey See [unified diff file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format)

Comment: @LotPings - ah! thank you for that ... i never even thot to look. [*blush*]

Comment: LotPings suggestion will work for diffs comparing 2 files. If you have a diff of multiple files in a single file use `-match '^[-+]'` for extracting the difference lines and `-notmatch '^(---|+++) '` for excluding the lines with the paths of the files compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
^[-+][0-9].*
```

The regex will get you any line that starts with + OR - folowed by a number

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3eHj4E/2)

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to do it. i could not work out a regex that worked on all the variants listed in the link by LotPings, so i went with string operators. this is likely *much* slower than a purely regex solution, but it seems to work. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file as one multiline string
#    in real life, use Get-Content -Raw
$InStuff = @'
--- \\path\to\file2.txt 2018-12-27 12:11:20.000000000 -0600
+++ \\path\to\file2.txt 2018-12-27 12:11:24.000000000 -0600
@@ -259,13 +259,12 @@
 18684944<tab>10-01-20<tab>5.00
-21400198<tab>12-03-18<tab>75.21
 18684944<tab>10-11-20<tab>5.00
@@ -333,13 +332,12 @@
 26085691<tab>12-17-19<tab>144.28
-21400541<tab>12-03-18<tab>72.30
 21400541<tab>01-03-19<tab>72.30
'@

$ChangeLines = $InStuff -split '@@.+@@' |
    # get rid of any blank items from the split
    Where-Object {$_} |
    # leave out the header info
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    # split the context/change block into lines
    #    take the ones that start with either "+" or "-"
    ForEach-Object {
        ($_ -split [environment]::NewLine).Where({$_ -match '^[-+].+$'})
        }

$ChangeLines
```

output ...

```
-21400198<tab>12-03-18<tab>75.21
-21400541<tab>12-03-18<tab>72.30
```